# Send Unicode Exception Message to Client in MVC4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, unicode

I am using the solution below. It works great (using MVC4), but failed when the error message contains Unicode characters (they are all ended up as ??????).

[Send exception message in Ajax.BeginForm MVC 4 scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763993/)

Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in Advance

ps: I can't post a comment in the original thread because my reputation is low.

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution proposed by Furynation in my link above.

I have figured out a temporarily solution by converting the message to Base64 and send the Unicode over.

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription =
    Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filterContext.Exception.Message));
```

When the client side Ajax.BeginForm received the error, I use to following code to get back the error message in Unicode.

```
function (data, status, xhr) {
    var Error = DecodeString(atob(data.statusText));
}
```

I need to write another function DecodeString() to do the conversion, because atob() converts everything into 8bits ASCII (fortunately not into ????????)

```
function Decode(u) {
var a = [];
var i = 0;
while (i < u.length) {
    var v = u[i++];
    if (v < 0x80) {
    } else if (v < 0xE0) {
        v = (31 & v) << 6;
        v |= (63 & u[i++]);
    } else if (v < 0xF0) {
        v = (15 & v) << 12;
        v |= (63 & u[i++]) << 6;
        v |= (63 & u[i++]);
    } else {
        v = (7 & v) << 18;
        v |= (63 & u[i++]) << 12;
        v |= (63 & u[i++]) << 6;
        v |= (63 & u[i++]);
    }
    a.push(String.fromCharCode(v));
}
return a.join('');
}

function DecodeString(s) {
    var u = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        u.push(s.charCodeAt(i));
    return this.Decode(u);
}
```

ps. I can't post this solution in the original thread because my reputation is low.